# Lucid npm throws error

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am trying to run the Lucid app. In /code/Week03/lucid directory, when I run npm install I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code 126
npm ERR! path /workspace/code/Week03/lucid/node_modules/utf-8-validate
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! /usr/bin/env: 'node': Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-04-06T11_15_43_098Z-debug.log
```

Any solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change ownership of 'node'.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931624/usr-bin-env-node-permission-denied

```
sudo chown $USER /usr/bin/env/node
```